# can I use Facebook-C#-SDK designed for ASP.NET MVC SDK in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk, webforms

I am intending in creating this [tutorial](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&referringTitle=Documentation) in ASp.NET web forms. Is this possible?

Comment: so, what alternative do I have for an ASP.NEt webforms? I want to use facebook c# sdk, as it makes my life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is built on top of web forms so, yes you can do it on web forms, but no you can't do it without MVC.

There are some aspects of the MVC library that you can use with Web Forms without actually creating an MVC application, but this is not a case of simply cherry picking functionality - the project you are alluding to is intended to be built on top of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just use the facebook javascript library for the calls:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

The only thing is, you won't be able to use the DLLS which are mentioned in that tutorial since they were built for MVC. So basically, you will just create an ASP.NET webforms app which uses the Facebook javascript library for talking to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the JavaScript library for FaceBook with ASP.NET. No, you cannot use the project, as is, for ASP.NET WebForms, as it is MVC code. However, you can hack out the parts you want to use for an ASP.NET Webforms project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Facebook C# SDK for webforms without using MVC.

Just make sure you are referencing only Facebook.dll and Facebook.Web.dll

Facebook.Web.Mvc.dll is mostly a wrapper around Facebook.Web.dll which makes working with MVC much easier.

Comment: where can I find a tutorial for webforms with fb C# sdk?

Comment: download the latest source code and checkout the samples folder. anything that contains "AspNetWebForms" is an asp.net web forms example.